# Single user implementation for a specific application

Tags: c#, authentication

I have a requirement like this.

1. My application is an add-in to Excel. It uses a token to authorize a specific user.
2. There is a Red/Green indicator in the add-in to show application is online/offline.
3. If A is already logged-in by opening an Excel instance, my requirement is when other Excel instance is opened in the same machine, it should use the existing logged in information and show the status as online/offline in the new Excel instance. I saw an implementaion using Semaphore. However not sure whether that can be a good solution solving my needs.

How to achieve this requirement?

Comment: .. and what is your programing question? Sounds like it would better posted to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi Sra, Thanks. I want to decide on what to use to solve this requirement. Some of friends are suggesting Semaphore. Can anybody give some hints on how to achivev this?

Comment: What have you _tried_ so far?

Comment: That sounds very theoretical and is therefore a question that really belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

well a semaphore is good if you want to limit the number of instances, but in this case you don't, you want to do some very simple IPC.  If it were my requirement I would add a WCF service bound to localhost or named pipes.

on startup try to connect to it and find out what user is logged in, if you can't connect to it start the server.  You will also need some mechanism for another instance to take over server role in case the user closes the instance hosting the service.